# Efficient way to convert strings from split function to ints in Python

Tags: python, variables, casting

I have a string of data with the following format: xpos-ypos-zoom (i.e. 8743-12083-15) that I want to split up and store in the variables xpos, ypos, and zoom. Since I need to do some calculations with these number I'd like to convert them to integers right from the beginning. Currently, the way I'm doing this is with the following code:

```
file = '8743-12083-15'
xval, yval, zoom  = file.split("-")
xval = int(xval)
yval = int(yval)
```

It seems to me there should be a more efficient way of doing this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 104, accepted):

My original suggestion with a list comprehension.

```
test = '8743-12083-15'
lst_int = [int(x) for x in test.split("-")]
```

**EDIT:**

As to which is most efficient (cpu-cyclewise) is something that should always be tested.
Some quick testing on my Python 2.6 install indicates **map** is probably the most efficient candidate here (building a list of integers from a value-splitted string). Note that the difference is so small that this does not really matter until you are doing this millions of times (and it is a proven bottleneck)...

```
def v1():
 return [int(x) for x in '8743-12083-15'.split('-')]

def v2():
 return map(int, '8743-12083-15'.split('-'))

import timeit
print "v1", timeit.Timer('v1()', 'from __main__ import v1').timeit(500000)
print "v2", timeit.Timer('v2()', 'from __main__ import v2').timeit(500000)

> output v1 3.73336911201 
> output v2 3.44717001915
```

Comment: map is usually faster than comprehension when using a builtin functions, and slower if you are using a user defined function (including lambda)

Answer (score 22):

efficient as in fewer lines of code?

```
(xval,yval,zval) = [int(s) for s in file.split('-')]
```

Comment: I'd declare this answer to be efficient as in "easiest to code and move on to other more important stuff, and to understand when I come back to it later".  Trying to eke out microseconds of performance from this particular line of code is clearly a detour into the Tarpit of Unnecessary Optimization.

Comment: I generally agree and that is exactly why I did not brush it up (although I am aware of the generator expressions and the like). But, since the matter in question is about *three* elements it might as well be left as is

Answer (score 17):

note: you might want to pick a different name for `file` as it shadows the buildtin

this works in Python 2 and 3

```
xval,yval,zval = map(int,file.split('-'))
```

Answer (score 13):

You can [`map`](http://docs.python.org/3.0/library/functions.html#map) the function [`int`](http://docs.python.org/3.0/library/functions.html#int) on each substring, or use a [list comprehension](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0202/):

```
>>> file = '8743-12083-15'
>>> list(map(int, file.split('-')))
[8743, 12083, 15]
>>> [int(d) for d in file.split('-')]
[8743, 12083, 15]
```

In the above the call to [`list`](http://docs.python.org/3.0/library/functions.html#list) is not required, unless working with Python 3.x. (In Python 2.x `map` returns a list, in Python 3.x it returns a generator.)

Directly assigning to the three variables is also possible (in this case a [generator expression](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/) instead of a list comprehension will do):

```
>>> xval, yval, zval = (int(d) for d in file.split('-'))
>>> xval, yval, zval
(8743, 12083, 15)
```

Comment: Don't worry, if you are assigning the map() to a tuple it will still work in Python 3