# Parse string into different types

Tags: python, string

I have looked at this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1574678/efficient-way-to-convert-strings-from-split-function-to-ints-in-python) but my requirements are slightly different.

I have a string of the form: `"command int1 int2"`, e.g. `"download 600 10"`.

I know I could use `str.split(" ")` to break the string into its component parts but then I would have to convert the 2nd and 3rd parameters to `int`s. Thus the following won't work (the `int` cast fails when it encounters `"download"` in the string):

```
(cmd, int1, int2) = [int(s) for s in file.split(' ')]
```

I'm still pretty new to Python... so I'm wondering if there is a nice, pythonic way to accomplish my goal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could maps types to values:

```
>>> types = (str, int, int)
>>> string = 'download 600 10'
>>> cmd, int1, int2 = [type(value) for type, value in zip(types, string.split())]

>>> cmd, int1, int2
('download', 600, 10)
```

Comment: No problem, enjoy.

Comment: `def strToTypes(string, types_tuple):
    array = [type(value) for type, value in zip(types_tuple, string.split())]
    return array

noun, n1, n2 = strToTypes("noun 3 4", (str, int, float))
print(noun, n1, n2)`

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your take on what "pythonic" means to you, but here's another way:

```
words = file.split(" ")
cmd, (int1, int2) = words[0], map(int, words[1:])
```

Answer (score 1):

There isn't anything more Pythonic in the standard library. I suggest you just do something simple such as:

```
cmd = file.split(' ')
command = cmd[0]
arg1 = int(cmd[1])
arg2 = int(cmd[2])
```

You could always try to look for a little parser, but that would be overkill.

Answer (score 1):

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1265665/python-check-if-a-string-represents-an-int-without-using-try-except) I have imported the following function, which use **isdigit()** [(see here)](http://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/str/isdigit.html):

```
def check_int(s): # check if s is a positive or negative integer
    if s[0] in ('-', '+'):
        return s[1:].isdigit()
    return s.isdigit()
```

Then you need only this code:

```
your_string = "download 600 10" 
elements = your_string.split(" ")
goal = [int(x) for x in elements if check_int(x)]

cmd, (int1,int2) = elements[0], goal
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this.

```
file = "downlaod 600 10"
file_list = file.split(' ')
for i in range(len(file_list)):
 try:
   file_list[i] = int(file_list[i])
 except ValueError:
    pass    
(cmd, int1, int2) = file_list
```